# Delphi TChromium Load From Variable Function Not Working

Tags: delphi, tchromium

I'm trying to execute this code in Form1.Activate Event:

```
Chromium.Browser.MainFrame.LoadString('<html>erg</html>', '');
```

But i get ACCESS VIOLATION error, whats a problem?
What i'm doing wrong?

Here is Code(not full):

```
    //-------------------------FORM ACTIVATE BEGIN
Form1.DoubleBuffered:=True;
//Get Task Panel Size BEGIN
TPanel.cbSize := SizeOf(TPanel);
ShAppbarMessage(ABM_GETTASKBARPOS, TPanel);
Task_Panel_Size:=(TPanel.rc.bottom - TPanel.rc.top);
//Get Task Panel Size END

    //Maximaze BEGIN
    FormMaximize();
    //Maximaze END

    //Load Default Page\\\\\\\\\\\\
    //Load First Part--ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+'Apps\Speed_Dials\index_Part1.html'
    //File_get_contents(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+'Apps\Speed_Dials\index_Part1.html');
    Chromium.Browser.MainFrame.LoadString('<html>erg</html>', '');
    //Chromium.Load(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+'Apps\Speed_Dials\index_Part1.html');

    //-------------------------FORM ACTIVATE END
```

> ***Problem is Solved, The Problem Was in that, what this Method not works in Delphi7 and thefor gives ACCESS VIOLATION error. But it works
>   great in Delphi 2010 :)
>   Thanks to everybody for helping :)***

Comment: Where in that chained member access is the AV. Break it into multiple lines with a single member access on each. Also, don't hide the error message from us. Give the full error message, verbatim.

Comment: Full errror is: Access violation at address 0047EB20 in module 'Project1.exe'. Read of address 00000000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried on Form1.Create Event?
Does it require it to be created as in "Chromium.Create"?

try this

```
var
  frame: ICefFrame;
  source: ustring;
begin
  if Chromium.Browser = nil then 
   showmessage('Not created');

  frame := Chromium.Browser.MainFrame;
  source := '<html>erg</html>';
  frame.LoadString(source, '');

end;
```

Comment: There is no Create method

Comment: Using this, i get this: [Error] Unit1.pas(117): Undeclared identifier: 'ICefFrame'
[Error] Unit1.pas(118): Undeclared identifier: 'ustring'
[Error] Unit1.pas(141): Missing operator or semicolon
[Error] Unit1.pas(141): Incompatible types: 'Cardinal' and 'String'
[Fatal Error] Project1.dpr(5): Could not compile used unit 'Unit1.pas'

Comment: Try ustring as they use that in there demo apps from what I read and also show a message box if Chromium.Browser = nil then you will know if its actually created or not

Comment: I have forgot to include ceflib.pas file into my USINGs :) Thanks for helping, it works very well!

Comment: Hmm, Your code is working, but if i'm using this : Chromium.Browser.MainFrame.LoadString('YO','');     Its not works, why?

Comment: Its not works again :( I pasted your code, included ceflib.pas file and it have worked, but when im closed my programm and runned it again, it gived same error(Access violation)... :(

Comment: If i trying this:   if Chromium.Browser.MainFrame = nil then
   showmessage('Not created');   It says Not Created

Answer (score 1):

you sould add second parametr **about:blank**
ie.

```
TChromium.Browser.MainFrame.LoadString ('<html>something</html>', 'about:blank');
```

Comment: Excellent! This modification made it work for Delphi XE5. I am using the gui client of DCEF3

Answer (score 0):

In Delphi 7 I kept getting an access violation error and changed

```
frame := Chromium.Browser.MainFrame;
```

to

```
frame :=Chromium.Browser.GetMainFrame;
```

I don't know why that works because I'm totally rubbish at this, but it does.
Hope this helps someone.